# How to insert data from one table to another table dynamically without using Triggers?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables say tab_1 and tab_2.
Now whenever i write an insert command on tab_1 data should get inserted into tab_2 also.
How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: First question would be why do you want to duplicate the data? There could be an alternative that doesn't involve storing data twice. Second question is why do you not want to use triggers?

Comment: And the reason to not use a trigger is?

Comment: This is exactly what a trigger would be good at - but you should consider strongly why you are duplicating data - that is for sure an anti-pattern

Comment: Guy's Thanks for replies. Well I sorted out this issue using the trigger as you mentioned. Now another problem i am facing here is how can i delete data in table_2 when data got deleted in the first table i.e, table_1.I am not getting idea to write the trigger for this help me out.

Comment: Rolling your own replication is always a bad idea. Either use a data access layer that does all components of work against all tables as a single unit of work (that can be transactional) or look into materialized views, which is probably more what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a multitable [INSERT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#sthref6444)

```
insert all
  into table1 (col1, col2, col4)
   values (col1, col2, col4)
  into table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
   values (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select col1, col2, col3, col4
  from some_other_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I like things simple. I believe in true MVC and would add the save to the second table in the model and call the model each time I save anything in the data layer.

In the model save to the first table then to the second table if first was successful. That is how I save to my local device and to the api server. Works well and have not had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger to delete should look like below:

```
create or replace trigger <trigger_name>
after delete on table1 for each row
declare
begin
delete from table2 where key_column = :old.key_column
end;
```

:old.key_column will be the key value for the row currently being deleted from table1.